# Spring - how to gather informations during rollbacks in declarative transaction management

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

Could please anybody tell me If it is safe and recommended to catch SQL and other exceptions within @Transactional methods ? When programmatic transaction management is used, I can simply catch the exception and do whatever I want, but I don't know if I don't break the transactional AOP system by catching these exceptions that would otherwise trigger the rollback ... if I do it declarative way.

I suppose there are proxies, that create a logical transaction with separate connection for @Transactional methods in the AOP advices. And they need to catch the exception that "I want to catch" and roll the transaction back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the transaction programmatically as rollback-only using this code

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

See [Rolling back a declarative transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back) in the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html).

But it's not recommended, because you are coupling your code tightly to the spring framework.

---

Perhaps, if you do that in more than one place, you should introduce a Helper Method, something like `TransactionUtils.rollbackCurrentTransaction()`. That way, if you decide to change your transactional approach (or god forbid, move away from spring), you only have to change one method.

Comment: what I meant is, I need to do stuff when the transaction rolls back...as I would if I could catch the exception where I could for instance log what happened or do something with the bean that was being persisted etc.

Comment: Well then that calls for an AOP advice inside the transaction advice. Read the Spring AOP reference ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html ) for info.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is indeed how Spring knows whether or not to initiate a transaction rollback. If you swallow the exception then Spring never has a chance to know that it should rollback the transaction.